# Librería dplyr en R

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo una variable `datos` con los atributos `ID_Producto`, `Categoría_producto` y `Venta`, que es una base de datos donde cada registro corresponde a una venta asociada a un `ID_Producto`, y pueden haber varios registros para un mismo producto.

Quisiera saber qué tipos de producto (`Categoría_producto`) son los que más se venden, por lo que quiero agrupar las ventas por producto, y ver a qué categorías corresponden el Top 5 de los productos vendidos.

Para ello, he escrito el siguiente comando:

```
datos %>% 
    select(ID_producto,Categoria_producto,Venta) %>%  
    group_by(ID_producto) %>% 
    summarise(sum(Venta)) %>% 
    top_n(5)
```

Sin embargo, el resultado que obtengo es una tabla que contiene `ID_Producto` y `sum(Venta)`.

¿Cómo podría incluir la Categoría de producto en la visualización de esta tabla?

Muchas gracias,
Ignacio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de una forma mejor, lo que se me ocurre es que una vez obtenidos los datos de interés, hagas un `left_join` con los valores únicos de productos y categorías:

```
datos %>% 
    select(ID_producto,Categoria_producto,Venta) %>%  
    group_by(ID_producto) %>% 
    summarise(sum(Venta)) %>% 
    top_n(5) %>%
    left_join(distinct(datos,ID_producto,Categoria_producto), by = "ID_producto")
```

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa al join posterior sería recrear explícitamente la columna `Categoría_producto` en el `summarise()`. En ese caso hay que asegurarse de que tenga, para cada grupo, largo 1, de lo contrario `summarise()` da un error. Eso es lo que hace `unique()`.

```
set.seed(2019)
datos <- data.frame(Categoria_producto = c(rep ("foo", 5), rep ("bar", 5), rep("baz", 5)), 
           ID_producto = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d","d","d", "e","e","e", "f", "f"), 
           Venta = runif(15, 1, 15))

datos %>% 
  group_by(ID_producto) %>% 
  summarise( suma = sum(Venta), 
             Categoria_producto = unique(Categoria_producto)) %>%  
  top_n(5, suma)
```

También se podría hacer usando `mutate()` y luego filtrando con `distinct()` un valor único para cada grupo.

Algo así:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(ID_producto) %>% 
  mutate(suma = sum(Venta)) %>% 
  distinct(ID_producto, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  ungroup( ) %>% 
  top_n(5)
```

Pero se me hace más complicado.